# How can I debug Gradle does not know how file '...' was created?

Tags: gradle

I have created a task in Gradle as follows:

```
task findTaskCreatingSpecificOutput() {
    dependsOn testClasses
    doLast {
        tasks.findAll { task ->
            task.outputs.getFiles().getFiles().each { output ->
                if (output != null && output.getAbsolutePath().contains('generated')) {
                    println task
                    println output
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

to try and find which two tasks are writing to the same `generated` location. However the output is a list of tasks and directories which do not overlap at all so it should be easy for Gradle to know exactly which task created the location.

Example output of `./gradlew clean findTaskCreatingSpecificOutput --info`

```
/Users/mylocation/shared/build/generated/sources/annotationProcessor/java/main
task ':shared:compileJava'
/Users/mylocation/shared/build/generated/sources/headers/java/main
task ':shared:compileTestFixturesJava'
/Users/mylocation/shared/build/generated/sources/annotationProcessor/java/testFixtures
task ':shared:compileTestFixturesJava'
/Users/mylocation/shared/build/generated/sources/headers/java/testFixtures
task ':shared:compileTestJava'
/Users/mylocation/shared/build/generated/sources/annotationProcessor/java/test
task ':shared:compileTestJava'
/Users/mylocation/shared/build/generated/sources/headers/java/test
task ':shared:delombok'
/Users/mylocation/shared/build/generated/sources/delombok/java/main
task ':shared:delombokTest'
/Users/mylocation/shared/build/generated/sources/delombok/java/test
task ':shared:delombokTestFixtures'
/Users/mylocation/shared/build/generated/sources/delombok/java/testFixtures
```

However I still get the warning `Gradle does not know how file 'build/classes/java/main/generated' was created (output property 'destinationDirectory'). Task output caching requires exclusive access to output paths to guarantee correctness (i.e. multiple tasks are not allowed to produce output in the same location).`

Comment: I also tried searching for `classes` and found that only `:shared:compileJava` writes to `/Users/mylocation/shared/build/classes/java/main`

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's any way to find out which task actually wrote any particular file. The code I used only lists the **declared** outputs.

In my case the problem was that I was running a bytecode weaving task in `doLast` for `compileJava`.

I've changed `compileJava` to write to a new directory using `destinationDirectory` and then the weaving task writes the updated classes to `sourceSets.main.output.classesDirs.singleFile`